# having trouble to this one answering this While loop

Tags: php

Here's my problem:

Use a while loop to write a program that displays the sum of the perfect squares of numbers 1 to 20. Use the variable `$counter` as the loop control variable. Create variables named `$squares` and `$sum` to hold the results. After and outside the loop body, use echo to display the string The sum of the perfect squares is `$sum`. The variable `$sum` should be replaced with its value.

Hint: A perfect square is a number that is the product of an integer multiplied by itself. For example, the perfect square of 2 is 4 since 2*2 = 4.

problem 1: Expected output is "The sum of the perfect squares is 2870."
problem 2: Expecting two occurrences of the variable named 'squares'.
problem 3: Expecting four occurrences of assignment operations that assign the  values to the variables 'counter', 'sum', and 'squares'.

here's my code:

```
<?php
    $counter = 1;
    while($counter <= 20)
    {
        $squares = $counter * $counter;
        $sum = $squares + $squares;
        echo "The sum of the perfect squares is $sum. \n";
        $counter ++;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: It looks like just your homework assignment, code and feedback from your instructor/auto checker. You need minimal understanding of what's going on, and not someone to write your code for you. Hints: check the value of each variable and your calculation. Do you really want to add `$squares` to itself in `$sum`? You can use a debugger or an interactive shell to evaluate or step through code. In addition, note where your `echo` statement is (should be outside the loop).

Comment: sorry sir but honestly its not my assignment ^_^ well that one with echo is wrong it should be outside the loop.. my bad that's from my workmate who made that code. i didn't go to school tho since i'm working as a web developer

Comment: here's my code <?php
$counter = 1;
while($counter <= 20){
    $squares = $counter * $counter;
    $sum = $sum + $counter;
    
    $counter ++;
  
}
echo "The sum of the perfect squares is $sum. \n";
?>

Comment: Still Studying Php and Python thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Thanks a lot ^_^ sir for your advice i got it although its different from your codes ^_^ sorry for my english here's my code

Comment: <?php
$counter = 1;
$sum = 0;
while($counter <= 20){
    $squares = $counter * $counter;
    $sum = $sum + $squares;
    $counter ++;
  
}
echo "The sum of the perfect squares is $sum. \n";
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
$sum = 0;
$squeares = array() ;        
     while($counter <= 20)
    {
    $squares[$counter] = $counter * $counter;
    $sum += $squares[$counter];

    $counter ++;

    }

    echo "The sum of the perfect squares is ". $sum;

    ?>
```

check it